# PHP Add one hour to current date time

Tags: php, date, datetime, time

here is my code for the current date time (now):

```
$my_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```

how can I add one hour while keeping that format?

Answer (score 27, accepted):

```
$my_date_time = date("Y-m-d H:i:s", strtotime("+1 hours"))
```

Answer (score 7):

You can do this simply with [`strtotime`](http://php.net/manual/en/function.strtotime.php) function:

```
$my_date_time = date('Y-m-d H:i:s', strtotime('now +1 hour'));
```

Answer (score 5):

Here we are using `DateTime` and `DateInterval` for getting desired output.

[**Try this code snippet here**](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/511f72edc5f35cd74450acc29fda6b80006753fd)

```
<?php
ini_set('display_errors', 1);

$dateTimeObj= new DateTime();
$dateTimeObj->add(new DateInterval("PT1H"));
echo $dateTimeObj->format('Y-m-d H:i:s');
```